# Show pop up on activity create fails

Tags: java, android, android-popupwindow

I am trying to show `popup` on `activity on create()` method but nothing seems to be happen .. No `exception` no `popup`.

Following is code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    txtPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    txtPassword.setOnTouchListener(otl);
    btnClear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    objDBHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = objDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long driverProfileCount = objDBHelper.getProfilesCount(db);

        initiatePasswordPopupWindow(); // show pop up when no data is in table

}

 private void initiatePasswordPopupWindow() {
    try {
        //We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater, use the context of this activity
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Login.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
      final  View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_password_popup,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.setting_password_popup_element));
        // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
        pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 600, 720, true);
        // display the popup in the center
        layout.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                Button cancelButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.end_data_send_button);
                cancelButton.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);
            }
        });

       /* TextView mResultText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.server_status_text);*/


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What i am missing ?

Comment: Are you sure that driverProfileCount is in fact equalt to 0?

Comment: Are you sure `driverProfileCount == 0` ?

Comment: show full code, as we cant tell if `driverProfileCount ` is zero

Comment: yup `driverProfileCount is 0` i have debug the code and it is going inside the `initiatePasswordPopupWindow` func

Comment: why dont you use `AlertDialog`

Comment: I have removed `if condition` for any confusion if `driverprofilecount == 0` but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use `post` with view (PopupWindow layout) that doesn't start it's messages queue. Try to use view that's already in activity, for example root view - change `layout.post(new Runnable() {` to `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        Button cancelButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.end_data_send_button);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);
    }
});
```